# Probability distribution for 1-dimensional random walk with pauses

Tags: probability, random-walk

The problem could be stated as follows :  we have some random walker in an unbounded 1-dimensional lattice, such that there is a 50% chance the walker doesn't move at all, a 25 % chance the walker moves to the left, and 25% chance the walker moves to the right. What is the probability of the walker ending up at some point in the lattice in $N$ steps?

If we now denote the position of the walker as an integer i.e. $1$ would refer moving one site in the lattice to the right, and $-1$ would refer to moving to the left. Then what sort of a distribution would describe the probability that the in $N$ steps the walker would end up at some specific point on the lattice? My intuition says that I am looking for sums of the terms in an $N$-tuple that add up to the point in the site. For instance the tuple described by $(1,1,-1,0,...,0)$ would put the walker at $1$ for the end point.

Comment: For the sake of clarity: since only left and right steps are allowed, are you referring to a unidimensional random walk?

Comment: Yes, only motion in the x-axis allowed. This question is related to a 2-dimensional walk where the walk ends when the walker has exceeded some boundary on the x-axis.

Comment: Let $P_N:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ denote the probability you are looking for. Then $P_N(x) = |A_N(x)| / 4^N$ where $A_N(x)$ is the set of $\{-1,0,0',1\}$-strings of length $N$ which sum to $x$ (here $0'$ behaves the same as $0$ under addition).

Comment: Yes, that is a good formal statement of what I desire. I'd like to find (if there exists) an explicit form for the size of the set $A_N (x)$.

Comment: Do you need an exact expression? Local CLT yields $P(S_n=m)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi n}\sigma}e^{-(m-n\mu)^2/2n\sigma^2}+o(1/n^{1/2})$ and in your case $\mu=0, \sigma^2=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Of course I would like an exact expression, but an approximation is good as well. If you are willing to flesh out your comment about this local CLT a bit more I am willing to accept it as an answer!

Comment: I learnt about the result [here.](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/275a-notes-5-variants-of-the-central-limit-theorem/) Search for "Discrete local limit theorem". Exact expression is $$P(S_n=m)=\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n+|m|}\sum_{i\le \frac{n-|m|}2}\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{2i}\binom {n}{|m|+i,i,n-|m|-2i}$$ but I don't know how to simplify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider independent steps in $\mathbb{Z}$ with *three possible outcomes* $\{-1,0,1\}$ and probabilities

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(X=-1)&=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{4}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}
  \end{align*}

We look at walks with length $N\geq 0$ starting from $0$.

> These walks follow a *trinomial distribution*, which is a specific instance of *[multinomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)*.
>   \begin{align*}
>   \mathbb{P}(X_{-1}=a,X_{0}=b,X_{1}=c)&=\binom{N}{a,b,c}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2a+b+2c}\\
> &=\frac{N!}{a!b!c!}2^{-2a-b-2c}
>   \end{align*}
>   with  $a+b+c=N$ and $a,b,c\geq 0$
>
> The probability to start at $0$ and stop at $K$ after $N$ steps is
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{{a+b+c=N}\atop{{-a+c=K}\atop{a,b,c\geq 0}}}\binom{N}{a,b,c}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2a+b+2c}\qquad N\geq 0, -N\leq K \leq N
>   \end{align*}

*Note:* This *[file](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MTH5118/Notes6-09.pdf)* presents some basic facts  about the trinomial distribution.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks: You're welcome! :-)